# Jest complain 'delete' is not a function of mongoose-delete(softDelete) library in nestjs

Tags: typescript, mongoose, jestjs, nestjs, soft-delete

I want to test the delete function written in the service file and the delete method is internally calling the delete function of the mongoose-delete library.

I am using Mongoose-delete for soft-delete, but the model created in the test file complains delete is not a function.

How can I write the unit test case for the delete function?

Here, I am adding the code snippets of the test file and service file.

Getting output/result:

```
  TypeError: this._geoRestrictionDocument.delete is not a function

  177 |     );
```

Please help me, here. Thanks in advance.

Should pass the test cases of the delete method.

test-file: geo-restriction.service.spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { GeoRestrictionService } from './geo-restriction.service';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { getModelToken, MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

import { Connection, Model } from 'mongoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { GeoRestrictionController } from './geo-restriction.controller';
import {
  GeoRestriction,
  GeoRestrictionSchema
} from './schemas/geo-restriction.schema';
import { SiteCommonService } from '@services/site-common.service';
import { JournalService } from '../journal/journal.service';
import { ConfigurationService } from '../configuration/configuration.service';
import { ConfigurationModule } from '../configuration/configuration.module';
import {
  Configuration,
  ConfigurationSchema
} from '../configuration/schemas/configuration.schema';
import { GeoRestrictionModule } from './geo-restriction.module';
import { mockSiteService } from '@mocks/mock-site-service';
import { mockJournalService } from '@mocks/mock-journal-service';
import {
  accountId,
  siteId
} from '@mocks/const-data';
import { createGeoRestrictionsDtoStub } from '@mocks/create-geo-restriction.dto.stub';

describe('GeoRestrictionService', () => {
  let service: GeoRestrictionService;
  let mongoConnection: Connection;
  let geoRestrictionModel: Model<GeoRestriction>;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI + '/';
    mongoConnection = mongoose.connection;

    geoRestrictionModel = mongoConnection.model(
      getModelToken(GeoRestriction.name),
      GeoRestrictionSchema
    );

    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ConfigurationModule,
        AwsModule,
        HttpModule,
        GeoRestrictionModule,
        MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
          useFactory: () => ({ uri })
        }),
        MongooseModule.forFeature([
          {
            name: GeoRestriction.name,
            schema: GeoRestrictionSchema
          },
          { name: Configuration.name, schema: ConfigurationSchema }
        ])
      ],
      controllers: [GeoRestrictionController],
      providers: [
        GeoRestrictionService,
        ConfigService,
        SiteCommonService,
        JournalService,
        ConfigurationService
      ]
    })
      .overrideProvider(SiteCommonService)
      .useValue(mockSiteService)
      .overrideProvider(JournalService)
      .useValue(mockJournalService)
      .compile();

    service = await module.resolve<GeoRestrictionService>(
      GeoRestrictionService
    );
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    const collections = mongoConnection.collections;
    for (const key in collections) {
      const collection = collections[key];
      await collection.deleteMany({});
    }
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('deleteServiceMethod', () => {
    it('should delete geo restriction', async () => {
      const insertedGeoRestrictionModelData =
        await geoRestrictionModel.insertMany([
          {
            ...createGeoRestrictionsDtoStub(),
            accountId,
            siteId
          }
        ]);

      expect(await geoRestrictionModel.count()).toBe(1);
      expect(insertedGeoRestrictionModelData.length).toBe(1);
      const deletedGeoRestrictionData = await service.delete(
        siteId,
        insertedGeoRestrictionModelData[0]._id
      );
      expect(deletedGeoRestrictionData).toBeFalsy();
      expect(deletedGeoRestrictionData).toBeNull();
    });
  });
});
```

service file :  geo-restriction.service.ts

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Request } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import {
  GeoRestriction,
  GeoRestrictionDocument
} from './schemas/geo-restriction.schema';
import { SoftDeleteModel } from 'mongoose-delete';
import { ExceptionService } from '@services/exception.service';
import { SiteCommonService } from '@services/site-common.service';
import { SbJwtService } from '@services/sb-jwt.service';
import { ConfigurationService } from '../configuration/configuration.service';

@Injectable()
export class GeoRestrictionService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(GeoRestriction.name)
    private readonly _geoRestrictionDocument: SoftDeleteModel<GeoRestrictionDocument>,
    @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request,
    private readonly _siteCommonService: SiteCommonService,
    private readonly _journalService: JournalService,
    private readonly _configurationService: ConfigurationService
  ) {
    this._journalService.createContext(GeoRestriction.name);
  }

  async find(
    siteId: string,
    geoRestrictionId: string
  ): Promise<GeoRestriction> {
    await this._siteCommonService.fetch(siteId, this.request);
    return await this._fetch(siteId, geoRestrictionId);
  }

  async delete(
    siteId: string,
    geoRestrictionId: string
  ): Promise<GeoRestriction> {
    const accountId: string = SbJwtService.getLoggedInAccountId(this.request);

    const geoRestrictionToDelete: GeoRestriction = await this.find(
      siteId,
      geoRestrictionId
    );

    await this._geoRestrictionDocument.delete({
      _id: geoRestrictionId,
      accountId,
      siteId
    });

    this._journalService.logDeleteAction(
      {
        oldValue: geoRestrictionToDelete
      },
      this.request
    );

    this._configurationService.populate();

    return null;
  }

  private async _fetch(
    siteId: string,
    geoRestrictionId: string,
    lean?: boolean
  ): Promise<GeoRestriction> {
    const accountId: string = SbJwtService.getLoggedInAccountId(this.request);

    const geoRestriction: GeoRestriction =
      await this._geoRestrictionDocument.findOne(
        {
          _id: geoRestrictionId,
          siteId,
          accountId
        },
        {},
        {
          lean
        }
      );

    if (!geoRestriction) {
      ExceptionService.badRequest(
        new LabelService({ geoRestrictionId }).replaceTemplateLiterals(
          LABELS.geoRestrictionNotFound
        )
      );
    }

    return geoRestriction;
  }
}
```

schema file: geo-restriction.schema.ts

```
import { GeoRestrictionTypeEnum } from '@enums/geo-restriction-type.enum';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';
import { SoftDeleteDocument } from 'mongoose-delete';

export type GeoRestrictionDocument = GeoRestriction &
  Document &
  SoftDeleteDocument;

@Schema({
  collection: 'geoRestrictions',
  timestamps: true
})
export class GeoRestriction extends Document {
  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'accounts'
  })
  accountId: string;

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'sites'
  })
  siteId: string;

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
    enum: Object.values(GeoRestrictionTypeEnum),
    required: true
  })
  type: GeoRestrictionTypeEnum;

  @Prop({
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Array,
    required: true
  })
  countries: [];
}

export const GeoRestrictionSchema =
  SchemaFactory.createForClass(GeoRestriction);
```